# Dom text reinterpeted as HTML when trying to use (this) in JS script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a vulnerarbility alert in Github which says 'Dom text reinterpeted as HTML'.

The js is.

```
$div.find('myclass').each(function () {
  let $this = $(this);
  $(".list").append(
    '<span>' + $this.text + '</span>'
  );
//
});
```

Im trying to find all elements of myclass in a div and create a list of those elements. I find the element and am creating a span element with the text of the original element and append it to .list. It works but am getting a warning.

Github suggests using .find to interpres the element as a selector to prevent XSS.

So have tried somethings like

```
$div.find('myclass').each(function () {
  let $this = $(this);
  $(".list").append(
    '<span>' + $.find(this.text) + '</span>'
  );
//
});
```

But none work.
What is the correct way here?

Thanks

Comment: _"Github suggests using .find to interpres the element as a selector to prevent XSS."_ - that makes absolutely no sense in this context. Your text content is likely not a valid CSS selector to begin with; and even if it was, _finding_ an element will return a jQuery object, and it makes little sense to try and "concatenate" _that_ into a string.

Comment: `$(".list").append($('<span></span>').text(this.text))`